# Enabling Prediction API in Google API Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-prediction

I am trying enable prediction API for one of my project where i have enabled billing.
But whenever i try to enable that service from old console it gives this error "An error has occurred. Please retry later."
When i am trying from new console it says "Enabling Prediction API..."  and never enables .
Can you guys help me out with this . I am facing this problem since yesterday .